# Which union filesystem is best supported?

Tags: filesystem

I'm interested in knowing the answer to this [unanswered question](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1430303) from the Ubuntu Forums:

> I am trying to get one folder to display the content of two other folders.
>   ...
>   I am a bit troubled by the different options.
>
> - There is unionfs, which seems to be available only via fuse in Ubuntu server, and not recommended as
>     it's [said to be buggy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1305391#5).
> - There is aufs, which people are [campaigning hard to get out of the kernel](http://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-installer@lists.ubuntu.com/msg00119.html).
> - There are talks about a VFS solution being developed but I can't find anything about it.
>
> What is the best solution to use?

Which union filesystem should I choose in order to have the best support in current and future releases of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aufs is the union filesystem used by default for schroot and the LiveCDs.  That's what I'd use, but you're right - there's not really an upstream union filesystem solution that I'm aware of.

Comment: Aufs does appear to be the least poorly supported, for this reason. It's a shame — there [isn't even a manpage](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/776657) for it!

Answer (score 3):

I can't help you pick the best solution, but for information on the vfs solution and a well written series of articles on linux union mounts, have a look at [A brief history of union mounts by Valerie Aurora](https://lwn.net/Articles/396020/). According to [a post on her blog in January](http://blog.valerieaurora.org/2011/01/07/last-day-at-red-hat/), it is not quite done yet.

Comment: Just to add a link to Valerie Aurora's page on union mounts : http://valerieaurora.org/union/

Comment: "I can't help you pick the best solution" — Fortunately, I only ask which filesystem is *best supported*. It's the difference between "Is Safari or Firefox better?" and "Is Safari or Firefox better supported in Ubuntu?"

Answer (score 2):

Added also here: [Cannot mount second drive at "/"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453043/cannot-mount-second-drive-at)

**Update**: [the overlayfs file-system has been promoted to standard kernel for version 3.18](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.18). So now there **is** an official union-type solution for linux; userspace utility to simplify its use will surely follow. 
For now, documentation is in the kernel tree at [`Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt).