# Cannot mount second drive at "/"

Tags: mount, filesystem

I have a second drive that I want to be mounted at the root. The drive contains the following folders:

```
/home
/shared
```

I want those two folders to be accessible at "/". I can mount the drive at /media/disk1 but that does not solve my problem.

I tried the following command but it doesn't work:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /
```

I have no errors but the folders do not appear on /

Comment: You can only have one partition mounted to a certain point (`/` here). You would have to create separate partitions for `/home` and `/shared`. Or you could just link `/home` and `/shared` to their locations in `/media/disk1`

Comment: @Nattgew: Actually you can! see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you seems you want is a "[union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount)" mount, which can't be done in Ubuntu (at least not with default tools; follow the above link you are adventurous). In general there is still **no** official union-mount solution in Linux (2014-04-22); there are out-of-tree filesystems like [AUFS](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/) and work-more-or-less-in-progress on [UnionMount](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/dhowells/linux-fs.git/log/?h=unionmount).  Valerie Aurora [has a (slightly outdate) page about it](http://valerieaurora.org/union/).

What you can easily do is mounting the disk at, for example, `/mnt/disk1` and then symlink the directories where you want them:

```
ln -s /mnt/disk1/home /home
ln -s /mnt/disk1/shared /shared
```

(again, you should **not** have an existing `/home` or `/shared` folder, confusion and/or errors would appear otherwise).

Another way to do these kind of things is a "bind mount". It's very similar to symlinking directories, but can cross "chroot" boundaries. You can find more info [in this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49623/are-there-any-drawbacks-from-using-mount-bind-as-a-substitute-for-symbolic-lin) and in [this other one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35084/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symlink-and-binding-with-fstab).

**Update**: [the overlayfs file-system has been promoted to standard kernel for version 3.18](http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.18). So now there **is** an official union-type solution for linux; userspace utility to simplify its use will surely follow. 
For now, documentation is in the kernel tree at [`Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt).

Comment: I will, I had to wait for the delay !

Comment: Well, something like a merge mount [can be and is being](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount) done in Linux.

Comment: Of course it can be done! unionfs for the win! (typically used in cases where you want a drive to be mounted readonly (fragile SSD with limited amount of write cycles, CDs...), but with possibility to write stuff (in ram with tmpfs, discarded when the drive is unmounted) during the session.)

Comment: I followed (years ago) discussions of union mounts on the kernel mailing list. The main kernel developers (Al Viro and Linus, I seems to remember) were not quite excited --- and semantic is really difficult, especially for delete white-out on multiple level mounts. Windows "Libraries" are similar things, and a royal source of headache (never know what you are really backing up, for example)

Comment: @Ruslan can you please add a link of a union fs (modern) pages for Linux? All I could find has reference to 2.6 or older kernels. Thanks! (PD I have corrected my answer)

Comment: Indeed, I'd love to see an updated answer to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/39850).

Comment: @Rmano according to [AUFS project page](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/), it is supported for latest kernels.

Comment: Yes, but read the first page of documentation: _Note: it becomes clear that "Aufs was rejected. Let's give it up."
According to Christoph Hellwig, linux rejects all union-type filesystems
but UnionMount_ --- which I suppose is the VFS solution, but I suspect it doesn't exist. Am I wrong?

Comment: ...about UnionMount: http://linux-kernel.2935.n7.nabble.com/Status-of-union-mount-td614826.html --- seems on the side of vapourware now. Again, I understand that the semantic problems are tough. In http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/dhowells/linux-fs.git/log/?h=unionmount last commit is around 10 months ago.

Answer (score -3):

You have to create the folders there, for example if you want the A drive there or a folder there, type:

```
 mkdir -p ~/
```

where    `~/`  is the directory after `/`, so `/` is the directory the file is being created in!

You can make any directory with this -- just instead of `~/`, type the directory you want the file to be created in. For example, for a file being made in `/usr/abc/`, type    `mkdir -p ~/usr/abc/`.  Hope this helps!